# Why do motherboards have oddball internal connections for USB to the front panel?

Tags: usb, motherboard, computer-building

This is something that's bugged me for many years. Everytime I go to build a new PC, I notice that the internal connection for USB is different than the external connection. I.e., USB 2.0 is just a bunch of header pins. USB 3.0 is a plug-in, and my latest build has a USB 3.2 connection that's even stranger. Why can't they just include the standard USB A, B, or C connections on the motherboard (like they do on the back of the board!) for the front panel? I don't get it. Electrically, they do the same thing!

Come to think of it, SATA and eSATA are the same way. Electrically no different, just a physically different shaped connector. WHY!!!?

https://pcguide101.com/motherboard/what-are-usb-headers/

Good guide for what they look like and do, but no explanation of WHY.

Comment: One important consideration is size. A standard USB-A plug is about 2cm of rigid inflexible material before you get to the bendable part of the cable. for many systems that's just way too big.  Most of that extra size is there to make the part more durable when users repeatedly plug/unplug it, but that isn't necessary when semi-permanently connecting it inside the case.

Answer (score 1):

Cost is the most likely factor, as well as compatibility. If you just put header pins on, the cost is a few cents. If you put a connector on, that cost will be ~10x as much, and you need to increase the pad size on the PCB to account for the connector header footprint.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Gen2 headers probably have the following benefits:

- It's easier (and therefore cheaper) to make connector "pins" lay against a small plastic piece, then sticking straight up out of the motherboard.
- You are also far less likely to bend pins installing connectors when they are "SATA" style, and also far less likely to install them the wrong way.
- USB3.2 is running at a very fast speed so quality of the connection of the cable to the motherboard might be more important than older versions.
- Power draw may also have factored into the designs.

Also, the "person" facing USB sockets are designed to be removable, which is not a goal with internal motherboard connectors.

Some eSATA connectors had a clip on them and I believe they were more rounder and robust than internal SATA cables, which was needed since they didn't just sit inside of a case for most of their life.

Comment: Thank you, good answer!